# Device does not wait for a response even specifying the hono-ttd - ECLIPSE HONO

Tags: curl, eclipse-hono, hono

I am using Eclipse Hono and I am experiencing an issue with hono-ttd, that is, when I launch the HTTP POST command from the device to send telemetry data by specifying e.g. hono-ttd=60, the device does not wait to receive a command instead it continues its execution. Moreover, I have no idea where to found the hono-cmd-req-id that should be returned by the device receiving the command.

This is the command I used to send telemetry data from the device:

```
curl -i -u demo-device@org.eclipse.packages.c2e:demo-secret -H 'application/json' --data-binary '{
  "topic": "org.eclipse.packages.c2e/demo-device/things/twin/commands/modify",
  "headers": {},
  "path": "/features/temperature/properties/value",
  "value": 45
}' http://${HTTP_ADAPTER_IP}:${HTTP_ADAPTER_PORT_HTTP}/telemetry?hono-ttd=60
```

After sending the above telemetry data, I expect the device to wait for a command. Instead, the device does not wait and immediately returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
hono-command: modify-response
content-type: application/vnd.eclipse.ditto+json
content-length: 361
```

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 0):

I have answered your question in the corresponding [Hono issue](https://github.com/eclipse-hono/hono/issues/3466).